# RabbitMQ .Net core

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit, easynetq

To configure a rabbitmq consumer in .net core I see examples of Console Application. I am not sure for production ready apps can a Console app would be a right fit as stand alone Rabbitmq Consumer. Please share your thoughts what's the recommended way of building a consumer and deploy to production. And also read that not to configure Consumer in ASP.net core apps as IIS could recycle and not a good choice

Comment: 1) There are many things factually incorrect with what you're saying.  2) I'm not sure what - if any - specific question you're asking.  3) If you actually have a question, I;m not sure SO is the best forum.

Comment: We dont share thoughts on SO, we share facts. Ask a question, get an answer :-)

Comment: Please see this link : https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Quick-Start

Answer (score 2):

if you want to pub/sub in .net core

first you need install lib RabbitMQ.Client

**Installing NuGet package RabbitMQ.Client**

then you can use RabbitMQ in .net core same Console Application.

You can see examples of the .net core 2.2 [here](https://github.com/RezaJenabi/RabbitMQ_Sample).

**Publish**

```
public bool Publish()
{
    var RoutingKey = "QueueName";
    var Body = "Message";
    var Factory = new ConnectionFactory
        {
            UserName = "guest",
            Password = "guest",
            Port = 5672,
            HostName = "localhost",
            VirtualHost = "/"
        };

        using (var connection = Factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.ExchangeDeclare("messageexchange", ExchangeType.Direct);
            channel.QueueDeclare(RoutingKey, true, false, false, null);
            channel.QueueBind(RoutingKey, "messageexchange", RoutingKey, null);
            channel.BasicPublish("messageexchange", RoutingKey, null, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Body));
        }

        return true;
        }
```

**Subscribe**

```
 public SubscribeResult Subscribe()
    {
        var Queue = "QueueName";
        var Factory = new ConnectionFactory
        {
            UserName = "guest",
            Password = "guest",
            Port = 5672,
            HostName = "localhost",
            VirtualHost = "/"
        };
        var subscribeResult = new SubscribeResult(); ;
        using (var connection = Factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {

            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: Queue, durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);
            var result = channel.BasicGet(queue: Queue, autoAck: true);
            if (result != null)
            {
                subscribeResult.Body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.Body);
            }
        }
        return subscribeResult;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

We're using RabbitMQ in a large .NET Core solution split into microservices. Each microservice is just a regular console app or ASP.NET Core, which then can be run on Windows as a service or as a daemon on Linux.

Starting from .NET Core 2.1 Microsoft introduced Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices namespace allowing to run ASP.NET Core as a Windows service: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

or you can use ServiceBase from Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility for console apps:
https://www.pmichaels.net/2019/01/08/creating-a-windows-service-using-net-core-2-2/

We're deploying mostly to Linux systems, so we use an approach of HostedServices:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<MyService>();
                })
                .RunConsoleAsync();
        }
```

```
public sealed class MyService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
  public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {}
  public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can host consumers in a Windows service, or a console app (which is basically what a service is, but with some start/stop behavior to interact with the Windows service control manager).

For Windows, you can use Topshelf. For Linux or Mac, you just use a Console app. And future versions of .NET core will likely integrate the service controls when you can use any console application as a service with a single statement in the configuration.

You can see examples of the console service [here](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ConsoleService) and there are many examples of using Topshelf for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory()
        {
            UserName = "guest",
            Password = "guest",
            AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true,
            HostName = "localhost",
            Port = 5672,
            DispatchConsumersAsync = true
        };

        var connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
        //services.AddSingleton(connection);

        //services.AddScoped(serviceProvider =>
        //{
        //    var conn = serviceProvider.GetService<IConnection>();
        //    return conn.CreateModel();
        //});

        var channel = connection.CreateModel();

        var basicConsumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(channel);
        basicConsumer.Received += BasicConsumerOnReceived;
        channel.QueueDeclare("queename", true, false, false, null);
        //publish test message
        //channel.BasicPublish("", "queename", false, null, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(" test message"));
        channel.BasicConsume("queename", true, basicConsumer);
        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }


    private static Task BasicConsumerOnReceived(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs args)
    {
        var body = args.Body;
        var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body.ToArray());
        System.Console.WriteLine(str);      
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

**

Comment: With the code I shared in .Net Core, you can listen to the rabbit queue without applying the console. Comment sections can be added to the service.